# Hi, I am making a contact form thingy, and my php isn't working any reason why?

Tags: php, html

Error: [image]

the code:

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to ="bejidev27@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New contact from " .$name;
    $body = "";
    
    $body .= "Name : " .$name. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Email : " .$mail. "\r\n";
    $body .= $message. "\r\n";
    
    if($mail !=NULL){
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    header("Location: index.html")  ;
    header("Location: done.html")  ;
}

?>
```

It's not sending the mail nor the page is working i need help ,thanks in advance :D

Comment: Do you have server running on `5500` port setup? And you should check if `$_POST` values are set before using them (e.g. when visiting page directly and not via POST request)

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed is usually what you get, when the webserver thinks you are trying to post to a "static" URL. It looks like your web server is not correctly configured to treat `.php` as PHP.

Comment: as @CBroe hinted at, there is *NOTHING* in this PHP code that could possibly produce HTTP 405. the problem is with your web server (nginx/apache/lighthttpd/iis/whatever), NOT with this php code.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your servers are running properly. Then, for the following

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

There need to be values for each you. If you are getting the values from a form, then you have to handle the form first using the 'isset' function, to be able to pass the values to each variables.